# What does the size="-1" mean in input element?

Tags: html, input

```
<input size="-1" value="Search" type="submit">
```

What does the size="-1" mean in input element here?

That can be seen here `http://www.postfix.org/`.

[image]

Comment: The size attribute specifies the visible width, in characters, of an <input> element. Probably is trying to do a "display:none" in there? Anyway as Praveen Kumar commented below, it should be a positive integer. And actually is not working fot type="submit"

Answer (score 7):

I would say that's **invalid**. According to [W3C Spec](https://www.w3.org/TR/html-markup/input.text.html#input.text.attrs.size):

[image: w3c]

Comment: That is not the spec. That is a reference and it says **This document has been discontinued and is only made available for historical purposes.**

Comment: https://www.w3.org/TR/html5/forms.html#the-size-attribute - you're still right about it being invalid :)

Comment: Just a note, won't work anyway with a positive integer in that case because of the type="submit"

Comment: @Kamae Good catch, it's actually being ignored for two different reasons.

Comment: @Kamae True that! `:D`

Comment: Ah... The craziness was, I was checking `<input type="search" />` LoL.